# Bootstrap pull-right does not work in card header on Safari, but work in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, bootstrap-4, safari, bootstrap-cards

[image: on safari] Cards on Safari

[image: on chrome] Cards on Chrome

Below is my code. I add pull-right class to card headers. It works well on Chrome but not work on Safari.
Does anybody know the reason or have any solutions for it?
Thanks very much!

```
        <div id='assigned-list' class="row">
            @foreach ($cardsAssignedToCurrentUser as $cardManager)
            <div class="card assigned border-primary mt-2 mr-2 col-sm-3">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <a href="#" class="card-link pull-right moveBtn">Unassign</a>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body unassigned">
                    <h6 class="card-text mb-2 text-muted">Last Four Numbers</h6>
                    <p class="card-number">{{ $cardManager->card->last_four_digits }}</p>

                    <h6 class="card-text mb-2 text-muted">First Name / Last Name</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        @if (strlen($cardManager->card->first_name) > 0)
                        {{ $cardManager->card->first_name }} @else None @endif
                        /
                        @if (strlen($cardManager->card->last_name) > 0)
                        {{ $cardManager->card->last_name }} @else None @endif
                    </p>
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{ $cardManager->card->id }}" />
                </div>
            </div>

            @endforeach
        </div>
```

Comment: Add "d-block" class on card-link

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it still does not work for me.